# Requests are getting wrapped with CDATA

Tags: java, wcf, soap

I am working on a java client for WCF, and have the template worked out pretty good. I was initially using the web service client project from eclipse but then found out the libraries needed aren't supported on the android platform. I was then going to use ksoap, but it gave me a lot of issues, so I got a copy of a working soap request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/getInt</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <getInt xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <i>42</i>
    </getInt>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And decided to make a template that would take in the value and stick it where the 42 goes. When I print it out, it looks like it should work great, but I noticed when I trace that my request is wrapped in CDATA tags.

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Header>
            <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/getInt</Action>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body>
            <getInt xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <i>100</i>
            </getInt>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
]]></MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

I am not sure why it is wrapped in CDATA, I am using a HttpURLConnection to make and send the connection. The code that handles that is shown below.

```
private static void sendRequest(String request) throws Exception
    {
        URL u = new URL(DEFAULT_SERVER);
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)uc;

        connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/html; charset=utf8");

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",SOAP_ACTION);

        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

        wout.write(request);
        wout.flush();
        wout.close();
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
    }
```

The request variable is what is shown above, at least what is wrapped in the CDATA tags. When I call System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage()); then it tells me Unsupported Media Type.
I am using Text as the messageEncoding in my binding configuration for the WCF server

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could get my java client to send the data correctly rather than in a cdata wrapper?

Thanks
Nick Long

edit:
I changed this line

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/html; charset=utf8");
```

to this

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/xml");
```

like it probably should have been to start with. I now get a 500 internal server error, so I'm not sure if I am any closer or not. Any suggestions are still really appreciated

Comment: Sorry, hit submit before I meant to, not sure how that happened

Comment: Sure would be polite for the folks that downvoted the incomplete question to rectify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first change I made was this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/html; charset=utf8");
```

to this

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/xml");
```

That was what got rid of the 415 error. After that I had the 500 error. What I did to fix that was I took this line

```
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/getInt</Action>
```

and removed it, making my template this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <getInt xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <i>%val%</i>
        </getInt>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The reason, I believe (someone please correct me if I am wrong) that I was getting the 500 error was that I had this line and the line I removed:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",SOAP_ACTION);
```

After making those changes, my client works great, and I have been able to take it to an image sharing client for the android.